# Is it bad to use polling in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have several `ArrayLists` which work as queues of data. Each of the queues is linked to an individual *thread* which checks if that `ArrayList` has some data in it.

```
 while (array.size == 0) {
    // nothing
 }

 // do stuff with one element of the array
 // remove element from array
 // and call the loop again
```

I have done similar things in embedded system programming, but is it safe to use this in Java? The concern is about process power waste by iterating around that while loop very fast.

It could be solved by adding `Thread.sleep(100)` and check every 100ms, but then again - slower response time.

The question is - do I need to add that sleep or I shouldn't be concerned about that?

Any suggestions on safer/better system to check for new data in arrays?

Comment: I use a delay of 250ms because I worry about the UI lagging behind..

Comment: Slightly longer answer: It depends. Polling is a great solution in many cases. You're not polling so much as you're doing a busy loop, which *is* a bad thing.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

ArrayList is not a thread safe collection, so if one thread adds data to your list, and another thread tries to retrieve data from the same list, you have no guarantee that the other thread will ever see the added elements.

And busy waiting like what you describe consumes cpu resources unnecessarily.

Since you seem to need a queue, why don't you use one, like [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html). It has a [`take` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) which will block, without consuming CPU cycles, until an item gets added to the queue. And it is thread safe.

Comment: +1 As the length is not volatile, the JIT is highly likely to cache the read value in a register so I would expect it to not see changes after it has warmed up.

Comment: Are you saying that volatile arraylist parameter size is not volatile?

Comment: @Arturs if your arraylist variable is volatile (let's call it `volatile myList = someArrayList;`), you have the guarantee that if you write a new value to it: `myList = someOtherArrayList;`, that new value will be visible by other threads. But that's it. If that variable keeps refering to the same arraylist and you modify that arraylist (by adding/removing) you have no guarantee that other threads will see the changes, or that they will see that the `size()` has changed.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: It might be better to say that it's "not `volatile`", or "not declared `volatile`", rather than "not volatile". Because in the OP's case, it really *would* be volatile -- it's just that Java would have no way of knowing that. :-P

Comment: @ruakh After `size()` is inlined, the JIT knows the field is not volatile and therefor doesn't need to be read each time.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Yes, I'm aware. What I'm saying is, the field *is* "volatile" (its value changes in a different thread), it's just not "`volatile`" or "declared `volatile`" (the programmer hasn't informed Java that its value can be changing in a different thread).

Comment: @ruakh I see your point. But given the class isn't designed to be thread safe, it is written correctly but can be mis-used.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Absolutely. I completely agree. :-)

Answer (score 11):

Unless the time that you need to wait is very very short, thus making a context switch too expensive, I would not use spinning. It definitely wastes CPU cycles for no good reason.

You should use `wait/notify` or some other signaling mechanism to suspend the thread and wake it up only when necessary.

Going to more advanced constructs, there are specialized data structures for producer-consumer patterns, like [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) (choose an implementation):

> A Queue that additionally supports operations that wait for the queue
>   to become non-empty when retrieving an element, and wait for space to
>   become available in the queue when storing an element.

Comment: polling helps if you have enough cores and want as fast as possible hand-offs... but if you can do that you'd not ask on SO at all (and need some OS access to pin threads to cores)

Answer (score 1):

How about using somehting like blocking queue that was released in java 5. I think this is recommended now over wait/notify which can get quite complicated. I've used it and it works well.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.ArrayList` is not thread safe at all. For queuing purpose, it's good to use `BlockingQueue`. It blocks thread call if queue is empty without consuming cpu. You can use `ArrayBlockingQueue` or `LinkedBlockingQueue` or other queue implementation according to your need.

Even you can implement it with `wait and notifyAll` but it is always recommend to use `BlockingQueue`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ArrayList, you can use a Concurrent collection, lets say, for example an ArrayBlockingQueue

```
ArrayBlockingQueue<YourObject> theQueue;
while(true) {
  YourObject o = theQueue.take();
 //process your object
}
```

In the other place, where you fill your queue, you just do an

```
theQueue.add(theElement);
```

The thread that is waiting for objects will "sleep" until there is an element. The add method will wake up the consuming thread.

You can read more about this class here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html

Answer (score 0):

Without a sleep your threads are going to loop as fast as they can and access the ArrayList, probably most times without any outcome.

I'd recommend to implement a Listener/Observer Pattern. If you can, have the producer which fills the ArrayList notify the appropriate threads on changes. Thus you would shift from a polling behaviour to a push behaviour.

Not sure whether that is doable within your architecture, would need further explanations on your system though.

Answer (score 0):

**What is Polling and what are problems with it?**

The process of testing a condition repeatedly till it becomes true is known as polling.

Polling is usually implemented with the help of loops to check whether a particular condition is true or not. If it is true, certain action is taken. This waste many CPU cycles and makes the implementation inefficient.
For example, in a classic queuing problem where one thread is producing data and other is consuming it.

**How Java multi threading tackles this problem?**

To avoid polling, Java uses three methods, namely, `wait()`, `notify()` and `notifyAll()`.

All these methods belong to `Object` class as final so that all classes have them. They must be used within a synchronized block only.

**wait()**-It tells the calling thread to give up the lock and go to sleep until some other thread enters the same monitor and calls `notify()`.

**notify()**-It wakes up one single thread that called `wait()` on the same object. It should be noted that calling `notify()` does not actually give up a lock on a resource.

**notifyAll()**-It wakes up all the threads that called `wait()` on the same object.

`ArrayList` is not a thread safe collection. Use `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

[Class ArrayBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html)